# How to compile the latest CN1 sources which require javax.media, org.cef etc?

Tags: codenameone

I just downloaded the latest version of the CN1 sources to use for building locally.

However, I don't have all the javax.media.* and org.cef.* that are required to build the JavsSE port.

Any quick tips on how to get everything to successfully build?

Since I couldn't build with the sources, I also tried copying the jars over from a just created CN1 project, but using those I get this error message:

```
/Users/me/NetBeansProjects/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaJMFSEPort.java:41: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import javax.media.Time;i
```

I'm no Java expert so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added new jars to the binaries repository: https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-binaries/

These should include both, see this commit: https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-binaries/commit/6aa7e9d76b3653598e12396d7defc50d624a4e63

Comment: Thanks! Btw, the error message in my question was due to an "i" I seem to have inserted by error into the source when I had it open.